# Swift - SQLite connection code explanation

Tags: c, swift, parameters, sqlite

I am currently trying to connect my iOS app with SQLite database I have on my computer locally, and while I have found a series of codes that work, I would like to understand how they work.

The below is from the post

Use sqlite3_exec to perform SQL (e.g. create table).

```
if sqlite3_exec(db, "create table if not exists test (id integer primary key autoincrement, name text)", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(db))
    print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")
}
```

I understand the if statement but why is there 3 nils in the parameter and where is sqlite3_exec coming from? is it bundled with C when I imported sqlite3.dylib? 
The next line as I understand defines errmsg as a string that displays the error message returned by sqlite3 along with the database name.

```
var statement: COpaquePointer = nil

if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "insert into test (name) values (?)", -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(db))
    print("error preparing insert: \(errmsg)")
}

if sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, "foo", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK {
    let errmsg = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(db))
    print("failure binding foo: \(errmsg)")
}

if sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE {
    let errmsg = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(db))
    print("failure inserting foo: \(errmsg)")
}
```

The above also raises some questions for me.
What is COpaquePointer? is it just a pointer?

Again the same questions about the parameter of the first statement `(db, "insert into test (name) values (?)", -1, &statement, nil)` Why is there `-1` or `nil`?

And is `SQLITE_OK` returned by SQLite?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html).

Comment: @CL. Thanks. Will do.